# define file path in .yml Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am needing define a path of file in yml file (I don't if in services.yml or config.yml)

I have a entity who find a table (in csv format). But this same file will be used in other class. So I need to specify him in a global file (yml file).

Something like that:

```
//Myproject/Entity/Myclass

class Myclass{

  public function foo{
     ...
     $file = "D:\workspace\Myproject\Symfony2\src\Myproject\MyBundle\Table\AMB.csv";
     $handle = fopen($file , "r");
     ...
  }
}
```

I wanna this '$file' be defined in yml file.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameters entry on `app/config/config.yml` and place your variables there:

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    myvar:      "value"
```

Then it will be available through the container on the controller with `$this->container>getParameter('myvar');` and directly on twig with `{{ myvar }}`

Comment: but I need use inside entity. Can't use container in entity.